# Android NDK Two Activities Use the Same JNI function

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI.

I have two (or more) Activities that want to use the same JNI function.
Currently I have to define two JNI functions that both call another function,
e.g.

```
int foo() { return 1; }

int Java_my_pkg_activity1_foo1(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    return foo();
}

int Java_my_pkg_activity2_foo2(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    return foo();
}
```

Is there a more convenient way to define just one JNI function that can be called by multiple Activities, so that I don't have to define Java_my_pkg_activityX_foo2() for every Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about defining a common class in the Java layer?  The method could even be static if you don't want to instantiate the new class.